# Gradle cannot publish artifacts to network/shared drive

Tags: gradle

I need to upload my archives to the network drive once gradle build is over. I have used 'file:', i am not getting any error, but i dont see anything uploaded. Tried to use scp, even this did not work. Please help me out.

Comment: Usually when I have trouble with files not appearing, it means that I have a bad path.  We could probably help better if you provide the relevant part of your build script and information about the path(s) involved.

Comment: Yes, actually it was the issue with bad file path. It worked when i changed the path accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, for gradle it does not make any difference if it is shared drive or local drive. I had to add escape chars and form the correct url to make this work